# Drupal: Display success/error message

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

how can I show users success/error messages without creating a node for it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need clarifications. Node is not used for printing error messages. Usually it showed via drupal_set_message('message', $status);

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`drupal_set_message($msg, $type = 'status');` lets you set a message, it will be displayed automatically on the next (or current) page the user visits.

The optional second argument lets you choose between an informational message (`status`), a `warning` (usually yellow) or an `error` (red).

See the docs: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_set_message/6

Answer (score 0):

Not really too sure what your question is, in your theme, there will be the variable

```
<?php
    print $messages;
?>
```

This will print any success/error messages to the screen. They are not stored as nodes.

For a complete list of drupal variables see the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/6)

Comment: Any ideas on best ways to get these messages from within the node template?

Comment: I tried 2 modules, Inline Messages http://drupal.org/project/inline_messages and Inline Form Errors http://drupal.org/project/ife, ended up using the latter and submitted a patch for both modules. Delivers nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in `settings.php` to disable the error messages:

```
$conf['error_level'] = 0;
```

See this blog: [from here](https://adipie.com/what-happen-when-we-show-error-messages-to-site)